# parse snmpwalk output to array

Tags: array, output, snmp

Im trying to get network interfaces by doing  a snmpwalk, but cannot separate in array, the variable stores all in element 0

ifname=(\$(snmpwalk -Oqv -v2c -c comm xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2))

This is inside a heredoc

How can i do that?

Comment: Can you pleaase be more specific how the output looks like?

Comment: The arrays of most shells don't have an element 0. Your shell must be a Korn-like shell such as bash.

Answer (score 1):

Your code nearly works.  The output of:

```
snmpwalk -Oqv -v2c -c public (somehost) 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
```

produces the desired output.  To store it in an array use `bash`'s `readarray` built-in.  The main caveat is that because of how pipes work with regard to sub-shells and environment variables, it is necessary to specifically redirect standard input (generally via command substitution), rather than pipe input into `readarray`, like so:

```
readarray -t if_names < <(
  snmpwalk -Oqv -v2c -c public (somehost) 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
)
for i in "${!if_names[@]}"
do
    printf '%d: %s\n' "$i" "${if_names[$i]}"
done

0: public
1: vlan3
2: igb1
3: igb2
4: igb3
5: lo0
6: vm-public
7: tun0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [`snmptable` (link)](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Snmptable) instead of `snmpwalk`.

There's a tutorial [here](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmptable).

Comment: Already tried something similar

snmptable  -v2c -c comm -Os xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IF-MIB::ifTable

Comment: The message was:

"Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)."

Is not simpler with snmpwalk? just one array at the time.

Answer (score 0):

What you had in the example will set the values into an array, with one small correction. I had to take out the escape \ before the $

```
bash$ ifname=($(snmpwalk -Oqv -v2c -c $comm $device 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2))
bash$ echo ${#ifname[@]}     # how many elements in the array
58
bash$ echo ${ifname[0]}      # item at index 0
"GigabitEthernet1/1/1"
bash$ echo ${ifname[1]}      # item at index 1
"GigabitEthernet1/1/2"
bash$ echo ${ifname[5]}      # item at index 5
"GigabitEthernet1/1/6"
```

You may find that this does not work if there are spaces in the return for the snmpwalk. Using IFS to limit input field separator to newlines only will help (see this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751373/8641637) which I found helpful in solving this problem)

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'      # newlines are the only separator
IN=($(my_command ...))
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

Comment: In `bash`, leaving `$(...)` unquoted does IFS-splitting (which you want here though you  need to tune it to set the separator you want) and globbing which you do **not** want, so you'd want `set -o noglob`. Alternatively, you can use `readarray -t array < <(snmpbulkwalk...)` which is a more correct, efficient and reliable way to get the lines of some input into a bash array.

Comment: Note that leaving those `$comm` and `$device`, `${ifname...` unquoted also implies split+glob none of which you want here. The only places where you've put quotes around variables where those where it was not needed (as they were in scalar assignment values)!